# how far does a redirection go in a command line?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I would like to undestand where a *stdin* redirection goes in an expression like `< <(cmd)`

as a test to learn more about bash I tried to write a bash function with `while .. do .. done` and to have it working I had to use a trial and error method , mainly because I did not know the behavior or the first redirection in `< <(find ...)`:

```bash
while read L ;do basename "$L";((k++));done <  <(
    find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '.*' |
    sort
)
```

With only `<(find ...` it does not work . I suppose it's because *stdout* of `find` command line goes to a tmp file ( so I read ) ; so I added one more `<` to "push" further the copy of *stdout* . That I can understand , but how can I know that *stdout* copied in the tmp file does not stop at the first command encountered : `basename` and goes as far as  *stdin* of `while` command ?

Comment: `<(...)` alone is not a redirection; it's a process substitution, that exposes the output of a command as if it were a file. the `<` between `done` and the process substitution is the redirection operator: it causes the `while` loop to use the process substitution as its standard input.

Comment: Everything *inside* the `while` loop inherits the loop's standard input as its own, which is why each `read` command reads from the process substitution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<(...)` by itself is a process substitution. It behaves like a file name, except the "contents" of the file it names are the output of the command. For example,

```
$ echo <(echo foo)
/dev/fd/63
$ cat <(echo foo; echo bar)
foo
bar
```

A `while` loop doesn't take arguments, which is why you get a syntax error without the input redirection.

```
$ while read x; do echo "$x"; done <(echo foo; echo bar)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<(echo foo; echo bar)'
```

With the input redirection, the `while` loop (which is a command, and like any other command, has its own standard input) uses the process substitution as its standard input.

```
$ while read x; do echo "$x"; done < <(echo foo; echo bar)
foo
bar
```

`while` doesn't actually *use* its standard input, but any command in the `while` loop inherits *its* standard input from the loop. That includes `read`, so each execution of `read` gets a different line from the file until the file is exhausted, at which point `read` has an exit status of 1 and the loop terminates.

Answer (score 0):

> how far does a redirection go in a command line?

The redirection goes for the whole duration of a *command* it is applied to.

There is shell grammar which defines the basic stuff that are inside a "command line". You can peak at [POSIX shell standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10) and [Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Compound-Commands).

> A command is one of the following:
>
> ```
> Simple command (see Simple Commands)
>
> Pipeline (see Pipelines)
>
> List compound-list (see Lists)
>
> Compound command (see Compound Commands)
>
> Function definition (see Function Definition Command)
> ```

A *command* may be a *compound command*, which may be a *looping construct*, which may be a `while` looping construct. A `while` is a single, one *command*.

The redirection is redirected for the whole duration of a command, and inherited for any commands inside that command.

```
while
    redirected here
do
    redirected here
done < redirection

if
    redirected here
then
    redirected here
else
    redirected here
fi < redirection

etc.
```